# elasticsearch backup/restoration from/to s3 - register error ( repository exception)

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, backup

i'm going to elasticsearch restore.
when use 2.x version, s3 repository register is well by script.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://'ip':9200/_snapshot/'repo_2016-12-14/?pretty'' -d '
{"type": "s3",
"settings":
{ "bucket": "'patch-backup'",
"base_path" : "elasticsearch/'2016-12-14'",
"region": "ap-southeast-1",
"access_key": "************",
"secret_key": "*************"
}}'
```

but when upgrade to 5.0 version, 
above scripts not operation. and show this error

```
{"error" : {
"root_cause" : [
{
"type" : "repository_exception",
"reason" : "[repo_2016-12-14] repository type [s3] does not exist"
}
],
"type" : "repository_exception",
"reason" : "[repo_2016-12-14] repository type [s3] does not exist"
},
"status" : 500
}
-
```

Comment: Have you installed the [AWS Cloud plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-aws#s3-repository)?

Comment: @Val yes! i install repository-s3

Comment: I am getting same issue, if I find a solution, I will update it here. Let me know if you already found the problem.

Comment: @animageofmine i just retry in next day morning. and then this scripts are operation.... :(

Comment: curl -XPUT 'http://'ip':9200/_snapshot/'repo_2016-12-14?pretty'' -d '

Comment: First list installed plugins and check if s3 there curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/_all/plugins'

Answer (score 14):

You need to install the repository-s3  plugin in all cluster nodes, then **restart** the nodes. Otherwise the plugin does not become usable.

Comment: This is clearly the right answer. Not obvious it made my day ! thxs

Answer (score 1):

**Motivation**: You need to backup your elasticserach data snapshot into aws s3 service, but You get an error that fails your connection to the elastic repository.

**Solution**: You need to make sure your **repository-s3 plugin is installed on all cluster nodes** ( installed and services restarted after ). afterwards register the manual snapshot repo and backup the data.

**For example** - Lets say you have 3 nodes running an elasticsearch docker:

```
- elastic-cluster-node-a
- elastic-cluster-node-b
- elastic-cluster-node-c
```

1.On all nodes you should install the right plugin:

```
#!connect to cluster node: ( for each a b and c)
 ssh -At <bastion-gw> ssh elastic-cluster-node-<node-number>

#!connect to elastic container:
docker exec -it <your-container-id> /bin/bash

#!install plugin
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install repository-s3

#!restart service
docker-compose restart elasticsearch
```

2.Verify your plugin is installed correctly on cluster:

```
curl -X GET http://<your-cluster-host>:9200/_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.plugins
```

3.Now you should register a manual snapshot on s3:

```
curl -XPUT <your-cluster-host>/_snapshot/my-snapshot-repo-name \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d @- <<'EOF'
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "s3-bucket-name",
    "region": "region",
    "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/TheSnapshotRole"
  }
}
EOF
```

4.backup your data:

```
curl -XPUT '<your-cluster-host>/_snapshot/repository/snapshot-name'
```

For more information check out [aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My mistake was only installing the plugin on the data nodes and not every node in the cluster, as instructed. Once I installed the plugin on the master nodes, too, this worked.